# Distorted graphics problem

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

My laptop is Asus N53S. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Installed bumblebee to use nvidia optimus (Nvidia  Geforce GT540M) - animations, performance in games are excellent.

But sometimes when I'm working with some programs I'm getting distorted display. Please look at screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an UX32VD with Optimus - I have used the following kernel options, and have never seen corrupted images..

Run this command in a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

That opens `/etc/default/grub` in a text editor. Add the following line to the file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nmi_watchdog=0 apparmor=0 pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1"
```

Save the file and quit the text editor.

Run this command to regenerate `grub.cfg`:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot afterwards.

Comment: it's seems everything is ok. thank you very much!